# DataTable throwing exception on RejectChanges

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datatable

I found this bug while working with a DataTable.
I added a primary key column to a DataTable, than added one row to that table, removed that row, and added row with the same key to the table. This works. When I tried to call `RejectChanges()` on it, I got `ConstraintException` saying that value is already present.
Here is the example:

```
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    var column = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(decimal));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
    dataTable.PrimaryKey =  new [] {column };

    decimal id = 1;

    var oldRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    oldRow[column] = id;

    dataTable.Rows.Add(oldRow);
    dataTable.AcceptChanges();

    oldRow.Delete();

    var newRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    newRow[column] = id;

    dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    dataTable.RejectChanges(); // This is where it crashes
```

I think since the row is deleted, exception should not be thrown (constraint is not violated because row is in deleted state). Is there something I can do about this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that this has the same cause than following bug issue since the first that will be rejected is your `delete` action:

[DataTable.RejectChanges() should rollback rows in reverse order](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/95389/datatable-rejectchanges-should-rollback-rows-in-reverse-order)

Two possible workarounds:

> Cycles through the DataRows rolling them back in reverse order. So the
>   new records are removed before the previous ones are brought back to
>   life.

```
DataRowCollection rows = dataTable.Rows;
for (int i = rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    rows[i].RejectChanges();
}
```

Disables constrains so the rollback can be done. Reenables constrains after that.

1. You could use LINQ-to-DataSet to define your own "rollback-order":

   ```
   var rollbackPlan = (from r in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                  where r.RowState != DataRowState.Unchanged
                  let firstOrder  = r.RowState==DataRowState.Deleted? 1 : 0
                  let secondOrder = r.RowState==DataRowState.Added?   1 : 0
                  orderby firstOrder ascending, secondOrder ascending
                  select r).ToList();
   foreach (DataRow r in rollbackPlan)
   {
       r.RejectChanges(); // Does not crash anymore
   }
   ```
2. Here's the way you "disable" constraints on a `DataTable` temporarily:

   ```
   var constraintBackup = dataTable.Constraints.Cast<System.Data.Constraint>().ToList();
   dataTable.Constraints.Clear();
   dataTable.RejectChanges(); // Does not crash anymore
   foreach (System.Data.Constraint c in constraintBackup)
   {
       dataTable.Constraints.Add(c);
   }
   ```

Comment: It is something similar, but I don't think it should rollback in reverse order. It should first reject changes on "non deleted" rows and than on deleted.

Comment: The second workaround will work (but how do you disable the constraint). The first is not a general solution because user can remove, for example, the last row, and than change id of the previous one.

Comment: @Vale: Edited my answer to show a way how you could force the correct rollback-order.

Comment: @Vale: Showed how to "disable" constraints on a DataTable temporarily.

Comment: That is the best solution so far. I will accept your answer soon if nothing better is suggested.

Comment: You can temporarely disable constraints with the dataTable.BeginLoadData() and dataTable.EndLoadData() methods.
(BeginLoadData disables constraints, notifications and index maintanance, EndLoadData re-enables all that.)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by using `unique` property of column tor `true`.

i.e.   `column.Unique = true;`

As soon as this property is changed to true, a unique constraint will be created on this column to make sure that values are unique.