# dataSet.RejectChanges() throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a **cached data manager** which fetches data from database and returns it to the grid. Every time that data manager has to fetch some data there is a method to clear dataset that consists of some other methods but also uses `_dataset.rejectChanges()` method.

**Problem:** _dataSet.rejectChanges() method throws "**RowNotInTableException:** This row has been removed from a table and does not have any data. BeginEdit() will allow creation of new data in this row." 
Also this exception isn't thrown every time, instead it's **random**. (I suspect other users interacting with my cached data manager and this causing some weird problems)
Is it even possible that other users might cause this problem(HOW?). Any fixes?

Comment: jus check this link you might get your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768066/datatable-throwing-exception-on-rejectchanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `cached data manager` is a red flag in an ASP.NET application.

`DataSet` instance methods are not thread-safe, so if multiple threads are updating the cached DataSet, all bets are off, and you can expect random "heisenbugs".

Use locking, or even better reconsider the design that caches an updateable DataSet.