# Unique contstaint error when rejecting changes on a DataTable

Tags: c#-4.0, datatable, datarow

I have a datatable problem when I reject changes on the table. I've created an example below which demonstrates the problem:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Last_Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Male", typeof(Boolean));

foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
{
    if (column.ColumnName == "Name")
    {
        column.Unique = true;
    }
}

DataRow row;

row = table.NewRow();
row["Name"] = String.Format("Steve");
row["Last_Name"] = String.Format("Smith");
row["Male"] = true;

table.Rows.Add(row);

table.AcceptChanges();
```

So at this stage I have a DataTable with a unique column constraint and 1 row in that table.

I now delete that row:

```
row.Delete();
```

This sets the rowstate to Deleted.

At this stage I realise that I've made a mistake and want to add the row again. So I create the new row again and add it to the DataTable:

```
row = table.NewRow();
row["Name"] = String.Format("Steve");
row["Last_Name"] = String.Format("Smith");
row["Male"] = true;

table.Rows.Add(row);
```

At this stage my DataTable contents are in the following state:

table.Rows[0].RowState is Deleted

table.Rows[1].RowState is Added

Now, I've changed my mind about the whole thing and want to get back to how I started so I call RejectChanges:

```
table.RejectChanges();
```

When I do this I receive the following error:

```
Column 'Name' is constrained to be unique.  Value 'Steve' is already present.
```

I understand that there are 2 rows with the same values but I thought reject changes would have ingored this as the RowStates are different.

Any ideas how I can get round this?

In my live code I use this to move rows between to 2 grids (like allowing the user to selected what columns are visible)

I'm using C#4.0 in Visual Studio 2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768066/datatable-throwing-exception-on-rejectchanges (duplicate)

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks, all working now. Poor job from Microsoft there!